# View which is always on top in Photoscroller Example

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiview, ios4, uiviewcontroller

i would have a uiview which is always visible in every zoom scale.

in the loadView method in PhotoViewController.m i tried following:

```
    [self.view addSubview:test];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:test];
```

... with no success....

can someone help me?

greets, phil

Answer (score 0):

as far as my knowledge there is a delegate method called after the zooming action

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
//write the bringsubviewtofront code here
}
```

It may works